# setSpeakerphoneOn not working in AudioManager in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing an app for Android. I am facing one problem. I couldn't put on the speaker. I use setSpeakerphoneOn function in AudioManager but it doesn't work.

```
  audioManager = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager;
  audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Kindly help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you need the permission of `android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`. Have you grant it to your app?

Comment: Yes, I have. But also It didn't work.

Comment: Okay, then I am not sure what to check next. Just one recommendation for the question, could you please change the example code block to what you are asking for? (i.e. `setMicrophoneMute` ->  `setSpeakerphoneOn`)

Comment: Sorry, I tried both putting on the speaker and muting the microphone. That's why I was at sea here.

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA I have changed my code (first line). Is it right?